# iCloud can't find my MacBook

Tags: macos, icloud, system-settings, find-my-mac

When I sign into [icloud.com](http://www.icloud.com) and click on the Find My iPhone icon, my MacBook does NOT show up in the located devices.  I have already made sure that my location services are turned ON in System Preferences and I have also made sure that Find My Mac is turned ON in the iCloud preferences in System Preferences. My computer IS connected to a wireless network.

This feature had worked in the past, but I hadn't tried to Find My Mac for a while and now it will NOT show up in the located devices.  I am also the computer's administrator.  iCloud's Find my iPhone program simply will NOT locate my MacBook.  I have tried turning off everything and then turning them back on (iCloud in System Preferences, location services, wireless connection, etc).

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe because its not located. I think they use Skyhook to do that or something that wouldn't work sometimes. MacBooks don't have GPS, it's possible that it didn't work.